# Swift 3 UITableView not updating after deleting from Firebase

Tags: ios, uitableview, firebase, swift3

I'm trying to delete items from a Firebase database when user swipes to delete on the UITableView.

I'm also using the nifty showActivityIndicator and hideActivityIndicator functions from https://github.com/erangaeb/dev-notes/blob/master/swift/ViewControllerUtils.swift in order to easily show and hide the activity indicator.

I can see both the database record as well as the JPG file properly deleted from Firebase when the following code is run.

But the problem is that the activity indicator never disappears from the screen, and the UITableView does not refresh.

In fact, the

```
print("Stopping activity indicator")
```

and

```
print("Reloading table view")
```

do not even run.

What am I doing wrong?

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == .delete {
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Delete Task", message: "Do you want to delete this task?", preferredStyle: .alert)
            let confirmAction = UIAlertAction(title:"OK", style: .default) { action in
                // Show activity indicator
                ViewControllerUtils().showActivityIndicator(uiView: self.view)

                // Retrieve Firebase reference to delete
                let repairItem = self.repairItems[indexPath.row]
                let storage = Storage.storage()
                let storageRef = storage.reference()
                let imageRef = storageRef.child(repairItem.imageRef)

                // Delete the item from Firebase
                repairItem.ref?.removeValue(completionBlock: {(error, ref) in
                    if let error = error {
                        print("Problem deleting item")
                    } else {
                        print("Item deleted successfully")
                    }
                })

                // Delete the photo
                imageRef.delete { error in
                    if let error = error {
                        print("Problem deleting photo")
                    } else {
                        print("Photo deleted successfully")
                    }
                }

                print("Stopping activity indicator")
                // Stop the activity indicator
                ViewControllerUtils().hideActivityIndicator(uiView: self.view)

                print("Reloading table view")
                // Reloading table view
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }

            let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .default)

            alert.addAction(confirmAction)
            alert.addAction(cancelAction)

            present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Part of the issue is that Firebase is asynchronous. The code following the removeValue closure is executing *before* the item is removed from Firebase. It's also a little unclear what repairItem, repairItem.imageRef, and what the expected result from imageRef.delete would be. I see you have a workaround but it shouldn't be necessary if the code is corrected.

Comment: @Jay `repairItem` is a custom struct, following the tutorial [here](https://www.raywenderlich.com/139322/firebase-tutorial-getting-started-2) very closely. `repairItem.imageRef` is a string pointing to where the photo is uploaded in Firebase storage. I've been Googling around for a "best practice" tutorial on how to synchronise UITableView with Firebase, and the previous link is the best I've found. But I just can't seem to find one for removing items. What would you suggest correcting? I'm not happy with my workaround because I'd like to understand the "proper" way of doing it.

Comment: I crafted a super simple answer/example - hopefully it will clarify at least one way to handle this task.

Answer (score 1):

Still not sure why the code below the Firebase removeValue and delete functions aren't running, but I managed to figure out a workaround.

Turns out that the code doesn't work only when I'm deleting the last remaining record on the table, after which the entire Firebase node is removed.

So I've added an observer to forcefully reload the table when this happens.

Under viewDidLoad(), I added the following lines:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // ... other preceding lines of code

    // Forcefully trigger a TableView refresh in case the Firebase node is empty
    refItems.observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
        if snapshot.exists() {
            print("Found the Firebase node")
        } else {
            print("Firebase node doesn't exist")
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    })

    // ...other following lines of code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to keeping a tableView and Firebase synchronized, there are two main options:

> 1) When removing a node from Firebase, manually remove it from the
>   tableView datasource when removing it from Firebase. No observer needed.
>
> 2) Attach a remove event observer to Firebase so when a node is removed,
>   your App will receive an event of which node it was, and remove it.

Here's an example; I am leaving the tableView code out for the sake of brevity.

Suppose we have a tableView that displays users. The tableView has a dataSource of usersArray which contain UserClass objects.

Given a Firebase structure

```
users
  user_0
    name: "Frank"
  user_2
    name: "Bill"
  user_3
    name: "Hugh"
```

We add three observers to the users node, childAdded, childChanged, childRemoved

```
class UserClass {
    var key = ""
}

var usersArray = [UserClass]()

let usersRef = self.ref.child("users")

usersRef.observe(.childAdded, with: { snapshot in
    let user = UserClass()
    user.key = snapshot.key
    self.usersArray.append(user)
    self.tableView.reloadData()
})

usersRef.observe(.childChanged, with: { snapshot in
    if let index = self.usersArray.index(where: {$0.key == snapshot.key}) {
        //update it in the array via the index
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    } else {
        //item not found
    }
})

usersRef.observe(.childRemoved, with: { snapshot in
    if let index = self.usersArray.index(where: {$0.key == snapshot.key}) {
        self.usersArray.remove(at: index) //remove it from the array via the index
        self.tableView.reloadUI()
    } else {
        item not found
    }
})
```

If a user is added, the .childAdded observer receives the new user so it can be appended to the array.

If a user is changed, the .childChanged observer receives the changed user. Grab the key, which would typically be the uid, locate it in the array and update the properties.

If a user is removed, the .childRemoved observer receives the removed user. Grab the key, locate it in the array and remove it.

In each case, reload the tableView after the change to the dataSource.

Answer (score 0):

you need to write code inside of block as below :

```
 imageRef.delete { error in
                    if let error = error {
                        print("Problem deleting photo")
                    } else {
                        print("Photo deleted successfully")
                      ViewControllerUtils().hideActivityIndicator(uiView: self.view)

                     print("Reloading table view")
                      // Reloading table view
                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                    }
                }
```

Comment: No, that still doesn't work. The activity indicator still shows, and the item is still visible on the table view.

Comment: The "Photo deleted successfully" and "Reloading table view" messages show on the console, but the activity indicator isn't disappearing. I've tried removing showActivityIndicator and hideActivityIndicator, but now the table view just sits there without deleting the row.

Comment: Kind of, but I think it's reloading "too quickly". I think the reload is triggering before the Firebase database entries are fully deleted, so the reload still tries to pull data from the database. Perhaps it would work better if I dispatch a queue to asynchronously delete the database item and photo?

Comment: no it will not trigger before the database deleted because your block invoked while your deletion process completes .